# Windows 10 Pro - how to allow remote access for software from another Win 10 Pro PC?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-access

I have 2 PCs

PC1 acting as a server and has Win10Pro - PC Name is PC52

PC2 acting as a client and has Win10Pro - PC Name is PC122

I have a software installed on PC1 and requires a user account from PC2 to be given remote access permission in Component Services > COM Security in order to access the server

These 2 PCs are on the same workgroup called WORKGROUP and so they can see each other in the network.

The username for PC2 is PC2\PC122. Is there a way to create a user account on PC1 using this same format of PC2\PC122? So far I have tried but the results are a user created called PC1\PC122 which doesn't work.

If I try to use PC1\PC122, I get an access denied error.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Is remote access on PC122 allowed in the first place? What's the software? Can you not configure it to use a PC122 local account for connection?

Comment: You need to clarify whether the two computers are on the same network or physically remote from each other.

Comment: Hi @Peregrino69, I can remote access to PC122 and vice versa. The application on client PC122 only asks for an IP address.

Comment: HI @John, the two computers are on the same network sitting next to each other.

Comment: Please add new info to your question instead of answering in comments so all relevant info is readily available for everyone to see. So question 1 - remote access is allowed, question 3 - I assume you mean "no, I cannot configure the application to use PC122 local account". Knowing the application would help us to help you resolve the issue. Also knowing exact error- or other messages you get is a great help.

Comment: the two computers are on the same network sitting next to each other.   ..........   Look in Advanced System Settings, Remote Tab and see if you need to change settings here. This is for remote assistance and not for folder sharing.